# Max Equation Length

Tags: python, optimization, equation, gekko

I read most of the questions with the same error, but most of them were answered the same which is not the case with my problem. I am solving a very easy model and the only issue is the conditional statement that I correctly managed. But I got this error and now I don't know how to fix it!
"APM model error: string > 15000  characters
Consider breaking up the line into multiple equations

[image: Code]

The may also be due to only using newline character CR
instead of CR LF (for Windows) or LF (for MacOS/Linux)
To fix this problem, save APM file with appropriate newline characters

STOPPING...
"
it will be great if you help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The Community Bot does have a helpful suggestion. Please post your code with ```python   ``` instead of an image of your code. One issue that I already see is the way that the looping is creating a long equation. Try using the `m.sum()` function. Also, just use `Pre`, not `Pre.value` in the equation. Equations are defined by `m.Equation()`. Once your code is posted, I can provide more specific suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do the summation with `IMODE=2`. Each data row and associated calculation is added to the objective function with `m.Minimize()` or `m.Obj()`.

Try using the `m.if3()` function instead of an `if` statement. This is required to provide the gradient-based solvers with continuous first and second derivatives. The `m.if2()` can also be used if `m.if3()` takes too long. There is more information on logical conditions in optimization problems.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import random
m = GEKKO()

# random numbers between -0.5 and 0.5
r = [30*(random.random()+1.0) for i in range(744)]

# power
Pw  = m.Param(value=r)
eta = m.Const(0.6)
Pre = m.Var(value=25,lb=20,ub=30)


def f(Pw,Pre):
    D = m.if3(Pw-Pre,Pw-Pre,eta*(Pw-Pre))
    return D

# constraint
#m.Equation(f(Pw,Pre)>=0)

# objective
m.Minimize(f(Pw,Pre))

# set global option and solve
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.solve()
```

The constraint `m.Equation(f(Pw,Pre)>=0)` is not needed because the absolute value is positive. This script gives the solution:

```
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            1
   Variables    :            6
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :            4
   Residuals    :            4
 
 Number of state variables:           3720
 Number of total equations: -         2232
 Number of slack variables: -         1488
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              0
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Model Parameter Estimation with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      1.95 NLPi:    4 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj:  7.00E+03 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    1.99689999999828      sec
 Objective      :    7001.86498359946     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Don't forget to post your code, not an image of your code next time you ask a question. It makes it easier to provide more specific suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the time you put into it. I corrected my own model and now it works. but I have another problem. with different initial values for the variable, it gives a different answer! not the optimal one! but this should have one answer.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the time you put into it. I corrected my own model and now it works. but I have another problem. with different initial values for the variable, it gives a different answer! not the optimal one! but this should have one answer.
I do not understand why!

```
    try:
       from pip import main as pipmain
    except:
      from pip._internal import main as pipmain
    pipmain(['install','gekko'])

    from gekko import GEKKO    
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    #Initialize Model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)

    #define parameter
    df=pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\....')
    Pw=pd.DataFrame(df).values
    eta = m.Const(value=0.6)
    Pre=m.Var(lb=20, ub=30)
    Pre.value=23


    def f(Pw,Pre):
        Dplus=m.Var(value=0)
        Dminus=m.Var(value=0)
        for i in range(744):
           D=float(Pw[i])-Pre.value
           if D>=0:
              Dplus.value=Dplus.value+D*eta.value
           elif D<0:
              Dminus.value=Dminus.value+D
        return Dplus+Dminus

  #constraint:
  m.Equation(f(Pw,Pre)>=0)

  #Objective:
  m.Minimize(f(Pw,Pre))

  #Set global options:
  m.options.IMODE = 2 #steady state optimization

 #Solve simulation:
  m.solve()
```

Comment: As long as you're still experiencing issues, please do not post this as an answer, instead update the content of the post or open a new question with the unsolved problem.

Comment: Using `.value` to build equations only uses the initial value. As @lemon mentions, please delete this answer and post as a new question. It looks like you are making progress.

Comment: Thanks ; I asked my question as a new one.

Comment: Thanks! Please delete this answer (not the question though).